# Refactoring Qt Quick Cpp class into header and .cpp

Tags: c++, qt, refactoring

I have a Cpp Class which I want to refactor into a header and .cpp file. No problem normally, but when I try to do this Qt Quick one I can't get it to compile. It's fine if I put all of it in the header file, but otherwise I get various different errors depending on how I try to do it. Is there a proper way. I think it has to do with the Q_INVOKABLE bit, but not sure.

Here is my code...

```
#ifndef APPLICATIONDATA_H
#define APPLICATIONDATA_H

#include <QDateTime>
#include <QObject>

class ApplicationData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ApplicationData(){}

    Q_INVOKABLE QDateTime getCurrentDateTime() const{
        return QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    }

};

#endif // APPLICATIONDATA_H
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Should be possible. Show your try and error messages then.

Comment: @krOoze Thanks very much for your offer, I do appreciate it. I had gone back to the all-in-header version, and while I was trying to reproduce what I had done to repost it for you, I found that it just started working. I confess I don't really understand what was going wrong before. Spent hours trying, and then it just worked. Cheers.

Comment: I do not understand question. What doesn't mean "try to do this (refactor into a header and .cpp file) Qt Quick one I can't get it to compile.". The only thing I can think of is this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Comment: @Marek R What I mean is, I can refactor a C++ class from a main.cpp file into seperate main.cpp and class.h and class.cpp files, but I was unable to do this when the class referenced QT Quick things such as Q_INVOKE and QObject macro. However (see below answer), I seem to have done it by accident.  Also, thanks for the link. I have been using that site, but I'm brand new to C++, and find their examples too terse for my experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles but I'm not sure why it does or why it didn't:

```
//header file

#ifndef APPLICATIONDATA_H
#define APPLICATIONDATA_H

#include <QDateTime>
#include <QObject>

class ApplicationData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ApplicationData();  //constructor

    Q_INVOKABLE QDateTime getCurrentDateTime() const;  //function

};

#endif // APPLICATIONDATA_H


//.cpp file

#include "applicationdata.h"
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QObject>

ApplicationData::ApplicationData(){}  //constructor implementation

QDateTime ApplicationData::getCurrentDateTime() const{  //function implementation
    return QDateTime::currentDateTime();
}
```

Comment: As it should. Probably forgot something (include header, the const or ApplicationData:: being the common omissions)